# ReactJS input type="number" only responds to spinner buttons, not manual input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

Currently, I can only change the value of the input field through the spinner buttons.

[image]

But when I click inside the input to type in a number manually, the text cursor goes away and I'm unable to type inside. I can click on the input box WHILE typing, and that would work though. Below is a simplification of my React code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        quantity: 1
    }
}

//This is just making some API call, but am I supposed to do anything else here to update the value?
handleQuantityChange(e) {
    this.props.editQuantity({
        quantity: e.target.value
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <input type="number" value={this.state.quantity} onChange={this.handleQuantityChange.bind(this)}
    )
}
```

The numbers are reacting correctly, but only to the spinner buttons.

Answer (score 3):

The input is a controlled component, which means its value will always be that in the `value` prop. You can either switch to an uncontrolled component by using `defaultValue`, or update the state on every change so that the value can update.

```
this.setState({
    quantity: e.target.value
})
```

Comment: Ah, can't believe I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: Actually - it isn't working as I had intended still. Setting state was one issue, but I guess my real question is that I lose focus when I click on the input box. The text cursor goes away automatically and I'm not sure what's going on there.

Comment: Maybe your API call has something to do with it. Try posting the function `editQuantity`.

Comment: I highly doubt it. I'm using Redux, and all I'm doing is changing the Redux store with `editQuantity`. Maybe it has to do `ref` from [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)?

Comment: If you're using Redux, why is the component storing its own state for this?

Comment: Just realized that there's no point storing state if I'm using Redux lol. I'll fix it up on that part, but that still doesn't explain why the text field doesn't focus.